# How can I access a class variable in an initializer in Python?

Tags: python, scope, python-2.x

I thought that a `class` statement in Python creates a scope. But trying this simple code I get an error:

```
class A():
    foo = 1 
    def __init__(self):
        print foo 

a = A() 

NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
```

Why is `foo` not accessible from the initializer? What is the proper way to access it?

Answer (score 10):

Classes do **not** create a scope. This is documented in [pep 227](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/):

> Names in class scope are not accessible.  Names are resolved in
>       the innermost enclosing function scope.  If a class definition
>       occurs in a chain of nested scopes, the resolution process skips
>       class definitions.

and in the [`class` compound statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions):

> The class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see section [*Naming and binding*](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming)), using a newly created local namespace and the original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains only function definitions.) When the class’s suite finishes execution, **its execution frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved**. [[4]](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#id8) A class object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary.

Emphasis mine; the execution frame is a temporary scope.

To access `foo`, use `self.foo`:

```
class A():
    foo = 1 
    def __init__(self):
        print self.foo
```

or access the `A` class by name, or use `type(self)` to access the *current* class (which could be a subclass):

```
def __init__(self):
    print A.foo
```

or

```
def __init__(self):
    print type(self).foo
```